# Will+inf+before+present perfect weird structure?

Tags: phrases, tenses, conjunctions

I just saw this sentence and I didn't get it,

> The children will dust all the furniture before their mother has finished cooking.

I do get the cooking and the dusting, I just don't know when will/did they take place? And when am I supposed to use this weird structure?Or is it just wrong?

Comment: I feel like this is a weird subjunctive thing. Irrealis tenses in english are _weird_ sometimes.

Comment: First, will+inf+before+present perfect isn't the structure.  Second, there's nothing weird about the structure of that sentence.  "Will" casts the action of the main clause into the future, therefore "has" in "has finished" in the subordinate clause conveys the present time in that future (i.e. present perfect in that future).

Comment: @Hearth - First, it's not weird.  Second, a subjunctive, or irrealis, is not a tense but a mood.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I meant the interaction of tense and mood. I'm not a linguist, I just know english has weird stuff around how people use (or don't use) the subjunctive.

Comment: @Hearth Third, it's not talking about a hypothetical situation. It's either predicting or prescribing a real future event. It's something quite tangible.

Comment: I don't like it either, and would prefer either *The children will dust all the furniture before their mother cooks dinner* or *The children will have dusted all the furniture before their mother has finished cooking.*  Or *will have finished dusting* etc.

.

Comment: Since _dusting all the furniture_ is an accomplishment (i.e, it takes a period of activity and has an end point), it would be clearer to say _They will finish dusting..._. When describing an accomplishment, one may be referring either to the activity or to the result, and this way of stating it doesn't make it clear.